# Получение Bitmap через getDrawingCache (для View, значительно большего размеров экрана)

Tags: java, android

На некоторых устройствах не получается получить `Bitmap` из `View` через `getDrawingCache()`. Не на всех. На 4.4.4 SGSIII - все в норме, а на 4.1.2 GT-S7582 - не удается.

Вернее, сама функция выполняется, а вот когда пытаюсь узнать высоту или ширину полученного `Bitmap` - ругается на `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

ps.Сам `View` - больше размеров экрана устройства (в обоих случаях).

```
RelativeLayout rl_timer_to_send = (RelativeLayout) c.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.rl_timer_to_send);
rl_timer_to_send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
rl_timer_to_send.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap layer_timer = rl_timer_to_send.getDrawingCache();
float resizeTimerFactor = 851.0f / layer_timer.getWidth(); // java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null

Comment: Вот это решение оказалось единственным, которое работает на всех устройствах: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11937411/4579593

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код должен сработать:

```
RelativeLayout rl_timer_to_send = (RelativeLayout) c.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.rl_timer_to_send);
rl_timer_to_send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
rl_timer_to_send.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
rl_timer_to_send.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
rl_timer_to_send.layout(0, 0, rl_timer_to_send.getMeasuredWidth(), rl_timer_to_send.getMeasuredHeight()); 
rl_timer_to_send.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap layer_timer = rl_timer_to_send.getDrawingCache();
float resizeTimerFactor = 851.0f / layer_timer.getWidth();
```

Источник ответа [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339429/android-view-getdrawingcache-returns-null-only-null).

Comment: Пробовал этот способ. Как раз на старых аппаратах не работает...

Comment: @Chekist, странно.. Не ожидал, что на старых аппаратах неправильно работать будет.